# Using randomforest to predict clusters made by kmeans, IMDB 5000 Kaggle dataset

Tags: r, random-forest, k-means

I have made 4 clusters of movies based on imdb score, number of votes and gross profit. These are nice interpretable clusters with a BSS/TSS of 65%.

Now I would like to use randomforest to predict in which of four clusters a movie belongs based on other characteristics of that movie.

Is it wise to use 2 methods in this way? As something in me tells me it is not a good idea to (basically) make predictions with kmeans and try to predict those predictions with randomforest.

Kaggle IMDB 5000 DB: https://www.kaggle.com/deepmatrix/imdb-5000-movie-dataset